# how to get string between last two matched character

Tags: regex

I have a string of `aaaaaaaO.zzzzzzzz.OaaaaO.gggggggg.Oaaaaaaaa`

how can i get the string between last two words of `O.` and `.O` by regex

what i want is `gggggggg`.

thanks

Comment: I could be wrong, but AFAIK, [a word is any set of characters between two characters that are not alphanumeric](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), so you'll want something that matches `([oO][^\w]).([^\w][oO])` or `([oO][^\w])[\w]+([^\w][oO])`(or similar; I haven't tried those patterns). Then get the last match from the resultant array.

Comment: which programming language are you using?

Comment: Did anyone answer your question satisfactorily? It's customary to accept an answer if they did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match things between `O.` and `.O`, and assert that there are no more `O`s until the end of the line using a negative lookahead:

```
O\.(\w+)\.O(?!.*O\.)
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/q0do5i/2)

#### Explanation

```
O\.(\w+)\.O(?!.*O\.)
O\.                         # match "O."
   (\w+)                    # match and capture word characters
        \.O                 # match ".O"
           (?!     )        # negative lookahead:
              .*O\.         # There is no "O." anymore
```

Comment: You could remove `(?:.(?!O))+$` in favor of `(?!.*O\.)`

Answer (score 0):

Or [this](https://regex101.com/r/SXv6GS/4/). `.*[O][.](?<getthis>.*)[.][O].*`

Gives you a named capture group. 
The bit in parentheses () is the named group 'getthis'.

- You look for any character repeatedly,
- then specifically a O followed by a dot,
- Then the capture group you want.
- then a dot followed by a O after it.
- Then any character any number of times after it.

Comment: A more simple `.*O\.(.*)\.O.*` and substitute with `$1` would serve as well.

Comment: Yep that works too. $1 representing capture group 1 as opposed to naming it - which may be language specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these simple patterns which finds values in ((double parentheses)).
I use escape to make sure the dot sign does not counts as any character, but literally.

```
(O\.)[a-z]+(\.O)

aaaaaaa((O.zzzzzzzz.O))aaaa((O.gggggggg.O))aaaaaaaa
```

Or you can specify inside square bracket what character you want to search. the plus sign (+) makes sure thatit will find at least one character or more.

```
(O\.)[g]+(\.O)
aaaaaaaO.zzzzzzzz.Oaaaa((O.gggggggg.))Oaaaaaaaa
```

If you need a specific word, try this:

```
(O\.)(hello)(\.O)
aaaaaaaO.zzzzzzzz.Oaaaa((O.hello.O))aaaaaaaa
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: `(O.)` doesn't match an `O` followed by a `.`, but an `O` followed by any character.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I put an escape before all the dot sign. Thanks